# html background to the end of the last line

Tags: html, css

I have this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/_gsf_/MMJQW/)

Note that the content of the TD is completely arbitrary. Can I change the mark styles to propagate the background of the mark symbol to the end of the TD cell? Note the green background should stay as is.

```
<table border=1 width=500>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>foo and bar</span><br />
        <span>foo and bar</span>
        <span class="mark">¶</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.mark {
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: are you asking to move the mark to the right side always or extend the mark's background colour to the end of the cell no matter the content?

Comment: to extend the background

Comment: I am no sure if that can be done... but maybe someone will pull it off

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the Fiddle. No, I don't think you can do that with just CSS...the issue is that these are all inline elements.

Comment: this is what I was asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/9/
non of the answers had it exactly, but @[Nelson Menezes]'s and @threeandme's helped me to compile the final solution

Answer (score 2):

If you can control the width of the text within the `td` you could do something like this:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/6/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>paragraph background colour</title>
<style>
td p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
td span {
    background-color: red;
    padding-right: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border=1 width=500>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>foo and bar<br />
        foo and bar<span class="mark">¶</span></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: right`:

```
.mark {
   background: red;
   float: right;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/2/)

Comment: this moved the mark itself - i would like the mark to stay left and from its location to the end of the line to be with the same background

Comment: This is the closest result I could get so far -> http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/4/

Answer (score 0):

I got the following solution but it depends on the amount of text on the left side:

```
.mark {    
    background: red; 
    display:inline;   
    width: 100%;
    clip:rect(0px,420px,20px,0px);   
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/5/

Answer (score 0):

Not with CSS alone.

You need JavaScript to calculate the left offset to the parent `td` and then set the width of the `span`

Something like this (jQuery)

```
var m = $('.mark');
var p = m.parent();
m.width(  p.width() - m.position().left)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MMJQW/8/